# Knapsack but even amount of items

Tags: java, algorithm, dynamic-programming, knapsack-problem

So, it's basically the same problem as the 0/1 knapsack problem: n items, each having a weight w_i, and a value v_i, maximise the value of all items but keeping the total weight less than W. However, their is a slight twist: The **amount of items in the knapsack need to be even**. The result should then be the total value of all the items in the knapsack.

I tried the following:
I use two DP tables of size (n+1) x (W+1), DP_odd and DP_even. I filled them according to:

```
DP_even[i][j] = max( DP_even[i-1][j] || DP_odd[i-1][j - weights[i]] + values[i] )
DP_odd[i][j] = max( DP_odd[i-1][j] || DP_even[i-1][j - weights[i]] + values[i] )
```

The result (the total value) should then be in DP_even[n][W]. However, the result is incorrect. I just get two equal DP tables.

Here is the implementation:

```
public class KnapSackEven {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int[] weights = new int[] {4, 3, 3, 5, 1, 2, 7, 12};
    int[] values = new int[] {2, 1, 3, 15, 3, 5, 9, 4}};

    int n = weights.length;
    int W = 10;

    int[][] DP_odd = new int[n+1][W+1];
    int[][] DP_even = new int[n+1][W+1];

    for(int i = 0; i < n+1; i++) {
        for(int j = 0; j < W+1; j++) {
            if(i == 0 || j == 0) {
                DP_odd[i][j] = 0;
                DP_even[i][j] = 0;
            } else if(j - weights[i-1] >= 0) {
                DP_even[i][j] = Math.max(DP_even[i-1][j], DP_odd[i-1][j - weights[i-1]] + values[i-1]);
                DP_odd[i][j] = Math.max(DP_odd[i-1][j], DP_even[i-1][j - weights[i-1]] + values[i-1]);
            } else {
                DP_even[i][j] = DP_even[i-1][j];
                DP_odd[i][j] = DP_odd[i-1][j];
            }
        }
    }

    System.out.println("Result: " + DP_even[n][W]);

}
```

}

```
Result: 23
```

However, the result should be 20. Because the total value 23 can't consist of an even amount of items. It took the the items weigths[2], weights[3] and weights[5], but that's not an even amount... It should have taken weights[3] and weights[5].

For everyone that wants to see, here are the DP tables: (the first column is values[i], the second column is weights[i]:

```
DP_even:
0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
2   4   0   0   0   0   2   2   2   2   2   2   2   
1   3   0   0   0   1   2   2   2   3   3   3   3   
3   3   0   0   0   3   3   3   4   5   5   5   6   
15  5   0   0   0   3   3   15  15  15  18  18  18  
3   1   0   3   3   3   6   15  18  18  18  21  21  
5   2   0   3   5   8   8   15  18  20  23  23  23  
9   7   0   3   5   8   8   15  18  20  23  23  23  
4   12  0   3   5   8   8   15  18  20  23  23  23  

DP_odd:
0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
2   4   0   0   0   0   2   2   2   2   2   2   2   
1   3   0   0   0   1   2   2   2   3   3   3   3   
3   3   0   0   0   3   3   3   4   5   5   5   6   
15  5   0   0   0   3   3   15  15  15  18  18  18  
3   1   0   3   3   3   6   15  18  18  18  21  21  
5   2   0   3   5   8   8   15  18  20  23  23  23  
9   7   0   3   5   8   8   15  18  20  23  23  23  
4   12  0   3   5   8   8   15  18  20  23  23  23
```

Backtracking gives the solution: weights[2], weighst[3] and weights[5] => total values 23.

Even though the method seems like it could work, it still doesn't.

Is there another way to solve this?

Comment: [Minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) applies here.  We cannot effectively help you until you post your MCVE code and accurately describe the problem.
We should be able to paste your posted code into a text file and reproduce the problem you described.

Comment: @Prune I added the whole implementation including an example.

Comment: ... but not tracing output that illustrates the lists being the same, the elements chosen, etc.

Comment: @Prune I added the output now, do I need to add anything else?

Comment: That's plenty; thanks.  Retracted my closure and down votes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get a value of 20 by taking the 15 and the 5, so the result should be 20.

`DP_odd[i][j] = 0` isn't right because 0 items is not odd. The way it is now is symmetrical with `DP_even` so the result will be the same.

Instead, set `DP_odd[0][0]` to a negative number and check for these negative numbers in the other sums and don't allow them to be used.

So something like:

```
public class KnapSackEven {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[] weights = new int[] {4, 3, 3, 5, 1, 2, 7, 12};
        int[] values =  new int[] {2, 1, 3, 15, 3, 5, 9, 4};

        int n = weights.length;
        int W = 10;

        int[][] DP_odd = new int[n+1][W+1];
        int[][] DP_even = new int[n+1][W+1];

        for(int i = 0; i < n+1; i++) {
            for(int j = 0; j < W+1; j++) {
                DP_even[i][j] = -1;
                DP_odd[i][j] = -1;

                if(i == 0 || j == 0) {
                    DP_odd[i][j] = -1;
                    DP_even[i][j] = 0;
                } else if(j - weights[i-1] >= 0) {
                    if(DP_odd[i-1][j - weights[i-1]] >= 0) {
                        DP_even[i][j] = Math.max(DP_even[i-1][j], DP_odd[i-1][j - weights[i-1]] + values[i-1]);
                    }
                    if(DP_even[i-1][j - weights[i-1]] >= 0) {
                        DP_odd[i][j] = Math.max(DP_odd[i-1][j], DP_even[i-1][j - weights[i-1]] + values[i-1]);
                    }
                }

                if(i > 0) {
                    DP_odd[i][j] = Math.max(DP_odd[i][j], DP_odd[i-1][j]);
                    DP_even[i][j] = Math.max(DP_even[i][j], DP_even[i-1][j]);
                }
            }
        }

        System.out.println("Result: " + DP_even[n][W]);
    }
}
```

Comment: where do you mean with "in the other sums"? Where should I implement your restriction?

Comment: @G.M In the middle else-if block, check that you're not adding to any negative numbers.

Comment: This works fine for most inputs but for example if: `weights = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 20} and values = {8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 10}, and W = 20`, I get `result: 0`

Comment: @G.M If the middle conditions are false, then the last ones weren't running either because they were in an else block. I've restructured the conditions so they should work now.